# Theming switches off colours

Tags: codenameone

I have changed theme colours in the theme.res file with ResourceEditorApp and look and feel is OK in the simulator. When I run the theme on the device - it starts ok and then fails to different colour schemes after approx 3 seconds. I run in Eclipse with CN1 version 3.6, Can you please help.

Comment: I'm guessing you are seeing the [iOS screenshot process](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-ios.html) but I can't provide you with a workaround since you didn't specify which UIID's you changed and in what way. Screenshots of the theme entry device and simulator would have probably made it easier...